# Jquery works after inspect element is done in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, webkit, responsive-design

**Website link**:

```
[http://50.87.144.37/~projtest/team/design/Cece/][1]
```

**Jquery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pgHeight = $(window).height();
    //alert(pgHeight);
    $('.sitewid').css('min-height', pgHeight - 150)
    var ltHeight = $('.mainImg').height();
    $('.left').css('height', ltHeight);
    $('.links').css('height', ltHeight);
    var dHeight1 = $('.mainImg').height();

});

$(window).resize(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var lt1Height = $('.mainImg').height();
        //alert(lt1Height);
        $('.left').css('height', lt1Height);
        $('.right').css('height', lt1Height);
        $('.links').css('height', lt1Height);
        $('.social').css('top', lt1Height / 2.8);
    }, 50);
});
```

**Html**:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="sitewid">
      <div id="header">...</div>
      <div id="content" class="mainPg">
         <img class="mainImg" src="images/bnw.jpg" alt=" ">
         <div class="left">...</div>
         <div class="right mainRHeight">...</div>
         <p class="cls"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">...</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is a responsive design. The page works fine in Firefox but when viewed in Chrome and other webkit browsers, the jquery does not works as it is supposed to. The class "`mainImg`" will be a dynamic image. So the `.left` and `.right` are getting its height and that height is assigned to both the sections. When I inspect element in chrome or double click on ipad screen, the content gets into the desired position(s) but it is shown in haphazard manner when the page first loads. What am I doing wrong here? The script syntax is in head tag. I have learned jQuery myself so I am sure I am missing something here because I have faced this issue prior to this project too. :/

Comment: `Jquery works after inspect element is done`, huh!?

Comment: Did you not read the post?

Comment: Don't just post your entire code here, recreate the problem in a fiddle while using only the code related to it, just some advice as i personally tend to skip questions like yours due to all the code shoved in my face.

Comment: I am actually not sure why the issue is arriving, which is why I pasted all the jQuery. I have trimmed the code and just left the jquery related to this particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var pgHeight = $(window).height();
//alert(pgHeight);
$('.sitewid').css('min-height', pgHeight - 150)
var ltHeight = $('.mainImg').height();
$('.left').css('height', ltHeight);
$('.links').css('height', ltHeight);
var dHeight1 = $('.mainImg').height();
resizeWindow();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
setTimeout(resizeWindow, 50);
});

function resizeWindow() {
    var lt1Height = $('.mainImg').height();
    //alert(lt1Height);
    $('.left').css('height', lt1Height);
    $('.right').css('height', lt1Height);
    $('.links').css('height', lt1Height);
    $('.social').css('top', lt1Height / 2.8);
}
```

Comment: I mean to make the resize function as a separate javascript function and call it after document ready. It should work.

Comment: So I need to remove the window.resize and get that out of the document ready that is initialised the first time ?

Comment: No change occurred. If possible visit the link, you will see the changes made. Chrome displays the desired output when inspect element is done, really strange issue.

Comment: Not strange. The issue is that first time the resize function wont work automatically. So when you select inspect element the window will resize so the function will work. Same thing happens if you just minimize your window to lesser width and height

Comment: Thanks for the help Manu M but I resolved the issue. The height of "mainImage" was coming out to be zero in all the webkit browsers because Webkit browsers set the height and width property after the image is loaded. Instead of using timeouts, I used onload funciton.